# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() not supporting in IE 10 and windows 8

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-10, pagerequestmanager

I am facing some asp.net ajax problem in my application on IE 10 in windows 8. But it is running correctly in compatibility mode of IE 10.

You can see my live demo for this [**here**](http://www.usrentacar.co.uk/DefaultIE10.aspx), it works fine in all browser instead of IE 10 (also works fine in IE9 on windows 7).

Don't konw what is the reason?

on my page i am registering this event :-

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
   page_Load();
});

$().ready(function() { page_Load(); });

function page_Load() {
    //my code for onload registration goes here(it all working fine)
}
```

Please help me.
Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();` you can try jQuery   [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Eg.:

```
$('html').on('click', '.selector', function () {
    page_Load();
});
```

Comment: I am using update panel.. is this code also works for update panel..??

Comment: Yes this is a workaround but hardly an explanation to why it does not works in IE10

Answer (score 3):

The server might not recognize Internet Explorer 10 as a web browser that supports JavaScripts. Running windows update fixed the problems for me.

If you cant update your server, you can try to add/modify your ie.browser in app_browser folder.

> If you don't have access to the whole machine and/or just want to update a single project, use NuGet to install the App_BrowsersUpdate package. Your site structure in Solution Explorer will then look like the image at right. Note that NuGet uses .NET 4, so for systems that have only .NET 2, you'll need to get the ZIP file and put the new browser files in App_Browsers manually.
>
> .NET 4 Browser Update NuGet Package - http://nuget.org/List/Packages/App_BrowsersUpdate
>   install-package App_BrowsersUpdate
>   .NET 2.0 Browser Update NuGet Package - http://nuget.org/List/Packages/App_BrowsersUpdate.net20
>   install-package App_BrowsersUpdate.net20
>   Note that NuGet is VS2010 specific so if you don't have nuget.exe and .NET 4, you can also copy the .NET 2 updated browser files into ~\App_Browsers manually from this zip file.
>   Updating the whole machine is the preferred way to fix this.

- [Quote source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)